# Problems with setting up delivery costs

Tags: magento-1.7, table-rates, delivery

I have two options to order a product.

1. Pick up yourself (works)
2. Delivery, order below 30,- you have to pay 7,- and above there are no delivery costs:

I use Tablerates for this. I have uploaded a CSV and it is correctly done:

```
Land,Provincie,Postcode,"Subtotaal bestelling (en hierboven)",Verzendkosten
*,*,*,0.0000,7.0000
*,*,*,30.0000,0.0000
```

Condition; price vs location

When I order below 30,- it adds 7,- thats oké

**But when I order above 30,- (subtotal) it still adds the 7,-**

I cleared cache etc etc.
Is there something I could have missed?

version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Did you first choose Price vs. Destination and then upload the CSV or the opposite?

Comment: Not sure. What order do you think is best, I can try again.

Comment: First you have to choose and save the Condition (Price vs. Destination) and then to upload the CSV.

Comment: By the looks of the csv header `Subtotaal bestelling (en hierboven)` I conclude that the condition is set to Price vs destination.

Comment: I have (re)set the tablerates and after that uploaded the CSV.
To test I changed the price to 7,10. When I order (with different browser) above 30,- it still adds the 7,10. When export the CSV it all looks good, I don't get it

Comment: I use a deliverydate extention but really doubt this breaks this..

Comment: nomatter what the orderprice in the basket is, it will add 7,- for deliverycosts.

Comment: I might be on to something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610138/table-rate-shipping-in-magento-1-7-with-wildcards-not-working I try to add country codes..

Comment: damned, doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be the tax. 
If you order something for $ 35, and your taxes are 21%, it calculates the order total by 27.25. So it doesnt fit in your free shipping rate.

in app/code/core/mage/shipping/model/carrier/Flatrate.php add the following code (around line 104)

```
// exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
        }
    }
    //////////// add this piece of code ////////////
    if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax()) {
    $taxableAmount = 0;
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $taxableAmount += $item->getTaxableAmount();
    }
    $request->setPackageValue($taxableAmount);
    //////////// till here ////////////
}

    // Free shipping by qty
    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        $freePackageValue = 0;
```

These are the rates Im using for a costumer, They had the same problems. When a costumer ordered something for 52,95, the shipping was not free, after adding the above code it was

```
Land,Provincie,Postcode,"Subtotaal bestelling (en hierboven)",Verzendkosten
BEL,*,*,0.0000,6.9500
BEL,*,*,49.9900,0.0000
DEU,*,*,0.0000,4.9500
DEU,*,*,49.9900,0.0000
NLD,*,*,0.0000,4.9500
NLD,*,*,49.9900,0.0000
```

Comment: I just did 28,3000 instead of the 30.0000 but thank you for a solution to that Marleen. I had the problem when ordering even for 1000,- the deliverycosts where added. I thought I fixed it but the problem came back. I reuploaded the CSV again and now it seems to be OKE. I'm still checking it every day if it keeps working :(